# How to display and hide a label on mouseover and mouseout event in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Wnen my mouse is on Label1, I want to show Label2 near to it. Then, when my mouse leaves Label1, I want to hide Label2. I tried with the following code. I am poor in javascript.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function LabelHover()
    {
        document.getElementById('Label1').style.display = 'inherit';
    }

    function Labelleave() 
    {
        document.getElementById("Label1").style.display='none';
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hello" Height="120" Width= "120" ForeColor="Brown" style=" left:220px; border:groove; top:15px " >
    </asp:Label>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Disclaimer" Height="17" Width= "100" ForeColor="Brown" onmouseover="LabelHover()" onmouseout="Labelleave()" style=" left:220px; " >
    </asp:Label>
```

Comment: Are the ID's of your labels actually set to Label1 and Label2?  Inspect them in Chrome/Firefox and verify that they're correct.

Comment: I ask because likely you're running into the ASP.NET Client ID legacy naming scheme.  Also, have you verified that LabelHover/Labelleave are being called (by either adding alerts/console output, or using javascript breakpoints in your browser)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function LabelHover() {
        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID%>').style.display = 'inherit';
    }

    function Labelleave() {
        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

And markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hello" Height="120" Width= "120" ForeColor="Brown" style=" left:220px; border:groove; top:15px; float:left; " >
</asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Disclaimer" Height="17" Width= "100" ForeColor="Brown" onmouseover="LabelHover()" onmouseout="Labelleave()" style=" left:220px;float:left; " >
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show or hide Label2 depends on Label1 then you have to add onmouseover() and onmouseout() at Label1 not Label2

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hello" Height="120" Width= "120" onmouseover="LabelHover()" onmouseout="Labelleave()" ForeColor="Brown" style=" left:220px; border:groove; top:15px " >
    </asp:Label>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Disclaimer" Height="17" Width= "100" ForeColor="Brown"  style=" left:220px; " >
    </asp:Label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function LabelHover() {
        document.getElementById('Label2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function Labelleave() {
        document.getElementById('Label2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: getElementById('Label2') is not a good practice as the label id would be generated from server and if it is inside a contentplaceholder it would be something like "ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2" rather than "Label2", will result in javascript error.

Comment: i agree if he/she creates a user control and register it to aspx page ,but in case he add these labels inside aspx page then no need for clientID

Comment: And you have to agree it would not work either if he /she is using any masterpage, right?

Comment: of course yes, if this label not in the same page (usercontrol,aspx,master page) as javascript function,you will need clientID, but if it's in the same page then you don't need it at all